# Parse Xml node values from CLOB field in ORACLE

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, clob, xmltype

I am trying to parse XML Node values from CLOB field and it is throwing invalid Token Error:
XML:

```
create table traptabclob(testclob clob);
insert into traptabclob values('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:InputOutputScoringDetails xmlns:tns="jdhajdjh"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="dasd.xsd ">
     <tns:InputsOutputs>
               <tns:NameValue>                                                            
                   <tns:Name>ABSC_APPLICANTBUREAUSCORE</tns:Name>
                   <tns:Value>0.11030000000000001</tns:Value>
               </tns:NameValue>
               <tns:NameValue>
                    <tns:Name>ABS_BN_SCORE_DETAIL_PK</tns:Name>
                    <tns:Value>10035</tns:Value>
               </tns:NameValue>
      </tns:InputsOutputs>
</tns:InputOutputScoringDetails>
                               ');
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(testclob), '/tns:InputOutputScoringDetails/tns:InputsOutputs/tns:NameValue[1]/tns:Name')
FROM traptabclob;
```

Can anyone help me as how can I use xmltype and extractvalue to extract values for Name or Value nodes?

thanks

Comment: The `tns;` is an xml namespace. You need to tell extract value about the namespaces, by passing a third argument giving the space-separated list of the `xmlns` values. So, the third argument would be `'xmlns:tns="jdhajdjh"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invalid token is the `tns:` namespace prefix. You need to supply the `tns` namespace information as part of the query:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(
    xmltype(testclob),
    '/tns:InputOutputScoringDetails/tns:InputsOutputs/tns:NameValue[1]/tns:Name',
    'xmlns:tns="jdhajdjh"'
  ) AS result
FROM traptabclob;
```

Although `extractvalue` has been deprecated for a long time, so you could use XMLQuery instead:

```
SELECT XMLQuery(
    'declare namespace tns="jdhajdjh";
    /tns:InputOutputScoringDetails/tns:InputsOutputs/tns:NameValue[1]/tns:Name/text()'
    PASSING xmltype(testclob)
    RETURNING CONTENT
  ) AS result
FROM traptabclob;
```

Both of those get:

```
RESULT
-------------------------
ABSC_APPLICANTBUREAUSCORE
```

Depending on what you're doing you might find it more convenient to use XMLTable:

```
SELECT x.name, x.value
FROM traptabclob t
CROSS APPLY XMLTable(
  XMLNamespaces ('jdhajdjh' AS "tns"),
  '/tns:InputOutputScoringDetails/tns:InputsOutputs/tns:NameValue'
  PASSING xmltype(testclob)
  COLUMNS
    name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'tns:Name',
    value NUMBER PATH 'tns:Value'
) x;
```

which gets:

```
NAME                                          VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------
ABSC_APPLICANTBUREAUSCORE        .11030000000000001
ABS_BN_SCORE_DETAIL_PK                        10035
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca660d75e7a8f03bc64010bc8f255d23)